# How can I exclude files in my .gitignore when packaging a Python egg?

Tags: python, django, egg

I'm packaging my first Django app and I want to leave out my settings_local.py file from the egg. Ideally I'm looking for a way to just have everything in my .gitignore file also excluded from the egg.

I've tried the following variations in my MANIFEST.in file (one per egg creation attempt):

```
prune project_name settings_local.py
prune project_name/settings_local.py
exclude project_name settings_local.py
exclude project_name/settings_local.py
```

I also tried adding the following line to my startup.py file (at the recommendation of a friend):

```
exclude_package_data= {'': 'settings_local.py'},
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a MANIFEST.in but use [`setuptools-git`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools-git) instead; with that package all files included in your git repository will also be part of the egg, and any files listed in `.gitignore` will not be.

I have the package installed globally, in my python's site-packages, but it should be enough to list it in your `setup.py` in the `setup_requires` structure:

```
setup(...
    setup_requires=['setuptools-git'],
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. I am embarrassed to admit the problem was that I didn't anticipate the top directory for setup.py when I initialized the local repo, so it was outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git archive` to produce a zip file with the contents of the git repository (like it would in a fresh working directory). Then you can use those files to package the egg however you need to.

See:
[git archive](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/git-archive.html)