# How to make setuptools honor .gitignore?

Tags: python, setuptools, gitignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
lib/
   lib/
      pkg1/
         __init__.py
      pkg2/
         __init__.py
      data/ # has many subdirectories and files
   tests/
   .gitignore
   setup.py
```

The `data` folder (not a package) has files and other subfolders, and some of them are excluded from the git repo due to `.gitignore`.

I want to `python setup.py bdist_wheel` this project and include the files in `data`, but I don't want any `.gitignore`'d file in the final wheel. Does `setuptools` support that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I exclude files in my .gitignore when packaging a Python egg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760764/how-can-i-exclude-files-in-my-gitignore-when-packaging-a-python-egg)

Comment: @NickODell that's a similar question, but here I'm asking about Python projects in general and wheels, and that question is about Django and  eggs. Besides, the accepted answer in there cites [setuptools-git](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools-git), a now abandoned project (last release was in 2017). All in all, I think my question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `setuptools` support that?

No, it does not. Maybe with an additional library such as [*`pbr`*](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/features.html#manifest) or [*`setuptools-scm`*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) on top of `setuptools`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setuptools_scm](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/) instead.